# Importing own font through @font-face isn't working with HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Font doesn't seem to link, tried everything i could think off. Any suggestions why it isn't working.

```
//CSS
@font-face {
font-family: 'fontOne';
src: url(../assets/fonts/fontOne.otf);
}

//JS

 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


 ctx.font = fontSize + 'pt fontOne';
 ctx.fillStyle = colour;
 ctx.fillText(dataVal, posX, posY);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for the font to be loaded by the browser before drawing to the canvas.  My favourite JavaScript library for this is probably [Font Face Observer](https://fontfaceobserver.com/).